# Splitting data into batches

Tags: split, pytorch, dataset, batch-processing, dataloader

I currently have the following data:

```
f_map, inputs, s_bias = ml_dataset.dataset_for_s_bias()
```

where f_map is a tensor of matrices, inputs is a tensor of floats, and s_bias is a tensor of floats. The first two, f_map and inputs, are the inputs to my ML regression algorithm, and s_bias is the expected output. The reason there are two kinds of inputs is because f_map is processed using a CNN, and the CNN turns each matrix in f_map into a float, which is concatenated with the inputs tensor, and the resulting tensor is inputted into an MLP to get a prediction for s_bias.

I don’t know how to split f_map, inputs and s_bias into batches. I tried using a dataloader, but this causes me problems in my CNN which expects a tensor (I have an unsqueeze operation in my CNN, but dataloader is incompatible with unsqueeze). I need f_map, inputs, and s_bias to be split the same way and preserve the order. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I'm confused by the question above. CNN turns f_map matrix into floats. But in general you inputs and weights should be of same data type and a matrix can be floattensor, longtensor or so on. coming to splitting into batches __getitem__() returns a single output of f_map, inputs, s_bias every time it is iterated. Next, i havent seen any where that dataloader is incompatible with unsqueeze operation. unsqueeze just modifies the size of tensor. Posting your could could help you get answers yo are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. When I was using the dataloader originally, I assumed that the dataloader itself was one batch. However, I needed to iterate over the dataloader to access the batches within. Those batches have the correct type (tensor).

Comment: This answer, while it seems that you have solved your issue, is not exactly for the question you asked. As it seems that the problem was a minor misunderstading, feel free to delete the question if you want.